# Как создать TRON кошелек на PHP?

Tags: php, blockchain, tron

Всем привет я создаю веб кошелек для блокчейна TRON, я бы хотел узнать, есть ли какой то способ для создания трон кошелька на PHP? документацию tronpy почитал, к сожалению ответа не нашел. Заранее .

Answer (score -1):

Когда то пользовался вот этим:
https://github.com/Fenguoz/tron-php

В библиотеке есть функция generateAddress.

Пример:

```
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$uri = 'https://api.trongrid.io';// mainnet

// $uri = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';// shasta testnet

$api = new \Tron\Api(new Client(['base_uri' => $uri]));


$trxWallet = new \Tron\TRX($api);

$addressData = $trxWallet->generateAddress();

// $addressData->privateKey

// $addressData->address


$config = [

    'contract_address' => 'TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t',// USDT TRC20

    'decimals' => 6,

];

$trc20Wallet = new \Tron\TRC20($api, $config);

$addressData = $trc20Wallet->generateAddress();
```